# Improve Unity 3D AR game performance [Low FPS]

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, async-await, web-worker, mediapipe

WE have created a Unity-based AR car game that uses the head position of the user for moving the car left or right similar to any simple mobile car race video game.
The game is a web-based AR game and uses unity WebGL output. As for head tracking, we are using Mediapipe.js. We have tested the experience on different OS  and the following are the fps results.

| Model | Browser | FPS & Range | Benchmark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MediaPipe Face Detection | Chrome PC | 62(60-74) | 60/100 |
| MediaPipe Face Detection | Chrome Android | 10(6-11 ) | 30 |
| MediaPipe Face Detection | Chrome IOS | 12(8-12 ) | 30 |

We are looking to achieve benchmark 30fps in mobile devices using Mediapipe. Any solutions or insights on improving the performance to make the game smoother are appreciated.

*references:*

- [Mediapipe Face Detection](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/face_detection#javascript-solution-api) {Model: @mediapipe/face_detection@0.4.1 | model-config: short}

*Tech-stack*

- HTML5/CSS JS(ES6)

Answer (score 0):

Start with profiling. First you need to understand what operations are slowing down your application. It could be:

1. Lots of CPU work per frame
2. Load on the GPU due to unoptimized and non-mobile shaders, a large number of vertices (100-150K+) or a large number of draw calls (if there are many different materials that are not batched)
3. Frequent memory allocation and deallocation

Comment: thanks for the advice, any profiling tool that you could suggest?